# incremental RMAN backups not rolling forward

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rman

We just switched from using datapumps over to using incremental backups with RMAN.  I've been having issues with the incremental backup pieces rolling forward. Here are my scripts for the backup:

```
BACKUP device type disk incremental level=1 tag='T4PRO' section size 1g database plus archivelog;
backup current controlfile format='&1CONTROLFILE_%T.BKP';
```

and the recover:

```
RECOVER COPY OF DATABASE WITH TAG 'T4PRO' UNTIL TIME 'SYSDATE-3';
DELETE NOPROMPT OBSOLETE DEVICE TYPE DISK;
```

Backup completes successfully, although the size of the backup copies seems larger than I had expected, but that's an aside for this discussion. My real issue is that we're on day 5 and are still getting this when I run the recover command:

```
RMAN> RECOVER COPY OF DATABASE WITH TAG 'T4PRO' UNTIL TIME 'SYSDATE-3';
Starting recover at 17-JAN-18
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=133 device type=DISK
no copy of datafile 1 found to recover
no copy of datafile 2 found to recover
no copy of datafile 3 found to recover
no copy of datafile 4 found to recover
no copy of datafile 5 found to recover
Finished recover at 17-JAN-18

RMAN> DELETE NOPROMPT OBSOLETE DEVICE TYPE DISK;
RMAN retention policy will be applied to the command
RMAN retention policy is set to recovery window of 7 days
released channel: ORA_DISK_1
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=133 device type=DISK
no obsolete backups found
```

The backup pieces are not rolling forward as I had expected them to two days ago.  Here are the results of a SHOW ALL command if it provides any additional information:

```
RMAN> show all;
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name T4PRO are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 7 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO 'C:\APP\ITWORKS\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\D
ATABASE\SNCFT4PRO.ORA'; # default
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if datafile copies exist:

```
RMAN> LIST COPY OF DATABASE;
```

Check if datafile copies exist with TAG 'T4PRO':

```
RMAN> LIST COPY OF DATABASE TAG 'T4PRO';
```

You must take a "image" backup using `BACKUP AS COPY...` before you can recover that image with an incremental backup.

Comment: I tried this. Given the way the files are laid out it makes more sense that it should work, but the restore command still failed.  The level 0 backup now looks like this:

`BACKUP AS COPY DEVICE TYPE DISK INCREMENTAL LEVEL=0 TAG='T4PRO' DATABASE;`

Comment: comment didn't complete for some reason.  The level 1 command is the following: `BACKUP DEVICE TYPE DISK INCREMENTAL LEVEL=1 FOR RECOVER OF COPY TAG='T4PRO' DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG DELETE INPUT;`  The recover command still produces the same output even on the fourth day even if you change it to 'sysdate-1'